# Why does this code not print anything when it is run?

Tags: java, filestream

I have stayed at this and for the life of me cannot figure out why when the code is run there is not display, ive tested and it will display the error message if i remove the file.

```
package binaryfile;    
import java.io.EOFException;    
import java.io.FileInputStream;    
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;    
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;

public class ReadBinaryFile {

       public static void main(String[] args) {                        
             String inStr="";    
             int countInt = 0, countDouble = 0;    
             int sumInt = 0, minInt = 0, maxInt = 0, numInt;    
             double sumDouble = 0 , minDouble = 0, maxDouble = 0, numDouble;    
             ObjectInputStream myObjStream = null;    
             FileInputStream fin = null;

             try {    
                    fin = new FileInputStream("data.dat");    
                    myObjStream = new ObjectInputStream(fin);

                    // loop to read the first 16 characters    
                    for(int i=0;i<16;i++)    
                           inStr += myObjStream.readChar();

                    // read an int and an double till the end of file    
                    numInt = myObjStream.readInt();

                    countInt++;    
                    sumInt += numInt;    
                    if(countInt == 1)    
                    {    
                           minInt = numInt;    
                           maxInt = numInt;    
                    }else    
                    {    
                           if(maxInt < numInt)    
                                 maxInt = numInt;

                           if(minInt > numInt)    
                                 minInt = numInt;    
                    }
                          
                    numDouble = myObjStream.readDouble();    
                    countDouble++;    
                    sumDouble += numDouble;

                    if(countDouble == 1)    
                    {    
                           minDouble = numDouble;    
                           maxDouble = numDouble;    
                    }else    
                    {    
                           if(maxDouble < numDouble)    
                                 maxDouble = numDouble;

                           if(minDouble > numDouble)    
                                 minDouble = numDouble;    
                    }                                                          
             } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {                               
                    System.out.println("File data.dat not found");    
             }catch(EOFException e)    
             {                                    
                    try {    
                           //     close the file    
                           fin.close();    
                           myObjStream.close();

                           // Display the results    
                           System.out.println("Characters : "+inStr);    
                           System.out.println("Total number of integers : "+countInt);    
                           System.out.println("Total number of doubles : "+countDouble);    
                           System.out.println("Sum of all integers : "+sumInt);    
                           System.out.println("Sum of all doubles : "+sumDouble);

                           if(countInt > 0)    
                           {    
                                 System.out.println("Minimum Integer : "+minInt);    
                                 System.out.println("Maximum Integer : "+maxInt);    
                                 System.out.println("Average Integer : "+(sumInt/countInt));    
                           }
                                  
                           if(countDouble > 0)    
                           {    
                                 System.out.println("Minimum Double : "+minDouble);    
                                 System.out.println("Maximum Double : "+maxDouble);    
                                 System.out.println("Average Double : "+(sumDouble/countDouble));    
                           }    
                    } catch (IOException e1) {    
                           System.out.println(e1.getMessage());    
                    }                                                          
             }catch (IOException e) {                               
                    System.out.println(e.getMessage());    
             }    
       }    
}
```

Comment: You don't print anything to the console so nothing will print unless our code fails... What do you expect to happen? Add `System.out.println("Your message");`
 if you want to print data to the console/output. Move everything inside your `EOFException ` to instead be inside the first try block.

Comment: It is _extremely_ annoying to read code with so many blank lines. Respect your readers!

Comment: You seem to be expecting to read to the end of the file, but evidently, the end of the file is _not_ read to.

Comment: After reading 16 chars, you need to to put rest of the code in an infinite loop. You are reading only one int and one double.